# ionic 2 - Using thumbnails and avatar inside ion-slide

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

In, Ionic 2,  inside 'ion-slide' doesn't render avatar and thumbnail images in avatar and thumbnail sizes, instead it displays in bigger sizes.

My code:

```
    <ion-slides>
     <ion-slide>
       <ion-item class="item item-trns item-stable">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="avatarImage"/>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-avatar item-right>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="avatarImage"/>
            </ion-avatar>
        </ion-item> 
     </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides> 

SCSS:
.avatarImage {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Cannot we use avatar inside ion-slide in ionic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change image width from width:100% to width:auto.

Comment: is it possible for you to attach an screenshot of inspect element - f12 in chrome dev tool

Comment: you were right. .swiper-slide img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

Comment: how to remove/override max-width: ? where to override?

Comment: In css, .place this line at last swiper-slide img {max-width:auto;}

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to remove the `max-width` property from the default SCSS, so that I would require only these two properties:

```
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: try `width: auto !important;` or override the `max-width` property

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="avatarImage"/>
</ion-avatar>
```

do this:

```
<ion-thumbnail item-left class="avatarImage">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
 </ion-thumbnail>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item-group>
<ion-item-divider color="light">PHOTOS<span style="float:right;">MORE</span>
</ion-item-divider>
</ion-item-group>


<ion-scroll scrollX="true" class="ion-scroll-thumbnail">           
<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage"
```

src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

```
<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

</ion-scroll> 

/* CSS */

.ion-scroll-thumbnail {
white-space: nowrap;
height: 90px;
}
```